# How to add another python project to my project as a sub-model?

Tags: python, include

I copied python project B to my project A as a model. But B's include path is just based on B. So how can I call B's function from A. For example,

```
.
└── mypackage A
    ├── subpackage_1
    │   ├── test11.py
    │   └── test12.py
    ├── subpackage_2
    │   ├── test21.py
    │   └── test22.py
    └── subpackage B
        ├── test31.py
        └── test32.py
```

test31.py may include test32.py by

```
import test32
```

But from A's prospective, I should include it by

```
import B.test32
```

In fact, B is more complex than this example. How can I refactor it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Wàlid Bachri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65407608/13616163) said, you should start placing `__init__.py` files, but it is a bit more complex than than.
You must put those `__init__.py` files, in each directory. So it would Look something like this.

```
.
└── mypackage A
    ├── __init__.py # here under A
    ├── subpackage_1
    |   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── test11.py
    │   └── test12.py
    ├── subpackage_2
    |   ├── __init__.py # under package 2
    │   ├── test21.py
    │   └── test22.py
    └── subpackage B 
        ├── __init__.py # under package B
        ├── test31.py
        └── test32.py
```

In each of the `__init__.py` files, you need to import all the files in the same directory. So for example in `subpackage B` you need to do this.

```
#/subpackage B/__init__.py
from . import test31
from . import test32
```

in `mypackage A`, where there are no files, just directories, you also do the same thing (`from . import subpackage_2` etc).

If I suppose that `mypackage A` is the "**main**" package (as can be seen by your diargam), so it is **not** a submodule, to run any file you will need to execute the following.

First `cd` to the **parent** directory of `mypackage A` and then

```
# Suppose you want to execute /subpackage_1/test11
python -m mypackage_A.subpackage_1.test11 # WARNING mypackage A should have no whitespace
```

You may get a `RuntimeWarning` about your `sys.modules` being modified, but I can assure you, from experience, that you can safely ignore it. This is how python modules for pip are normally done, to ensure that pushing to production is easy.

**EDIT** : Also note that in all of your files, you should switch to package imports for relative imports, so you must use the dot syntax.

```
from . import test32 # this will import .test32
```

if you were to instead to `import test32` from `test31`, the interpeter would try to search for a global package named `test32` and not look in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

first make module using `__init__.py` in B
then try this:

```
from B.test32 import 'function Name'
```

and then call it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an empty python file called `__init__.py` to your B project to make Python treat this project as a normal python module.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I'm afraid about the import path.

Comment: Try this `from B import test32`